# How to make a batch file that send application an input char

Tags: batch-file, keyboard, console-application, user-input

I'm writing a batch file that launch an application.

```
app.exe
```

After the application is launched, I'm getting a list of options in the console, and the program waits for input, for example:

> ```
> a: start session
>
> b: end session
>
> c: end
> ```

How do I make the batch type `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using `echo` as @npclaudiu suggested, you could also write the expected input to a text file and then have the app read the file:

```
app.exe <input.txt
```

This works if the app expects more than one line of input.

Comment: Well, it works only for the first line. For example- I want to open session and to close it immediately, so I put a and b in the txt file. It opened the session for the a and then say error reading option for the sec. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure if the application supports command line arguments. For example, at your command prompt, type:

```
C:\> app.exe /?
```

or

```
C:\> app.exe -h
```

or

```
C:\> app.exe --help
```

If it doesn't, try using

```
echo a | app.exe
```