# How to control .exe file with .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi I have program Program.exe which have some 3 parameters. And I am trying to control this program via .bat file. I can run this program with parameters without any problems, its easy. But if this program starts succesfully, then there are two choices what to do. For example if user type 'a' then this program writes on console 'hi'. If user types 'b' then program writes to console 'hello'. I want to somehow sent to this Program.exe only the 'a' choice after start. Unfortunaly I cant add another parameter. Does anyone know how to do it?
So here is my very simple .bat file.

```
Program %1 %2 %3
```

and I tried to add this command to .bat file but it doesnt works.

```
echo a > Program
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: *Exact duplicate:* [How to make a batch file that send application an input char](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6583690)

Comment: Too little information. Just because you can type something into a program doesn't mean that it will also read input from STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Echo a| Program %1 %2 %3
```

That is a known method for most CLI apps, but is not valid for all applications, if the pipe don't work for your app then forget to do it using native Batch and try a nircmd sendkey command or another CLI app to send keys.

Pipes: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

NirCMD: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html